# Calculate Time Difference of two consecutive rows in one column of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like

```
table1
____________________________________________________________________
UniqueID   TicketNumber   Action                    Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         123456         Dependency Occured        3/25/2015 7:40:39 AM
 2         123456         Tech Support requested    3/25/2015 10:00:47 AM
 3         123456         Tech Support Given        3/25/2015 11:30:40 AM
 4         123456         Dependency Occured        3/25/2015 02:30:40 PM
 5         123456         Tech Support Given        3/25/2015 03:30:40 PM
```

Here for the same **TicketNumber** there are various actions performed at a given time. Now I have to find total time  '*Dependency Occured*'.
So the Date of Action, for *Dependency Occurred* has to be subtracted from the row just below it, from that I have to calculate total time Dependency has occurred.
Like 1st row - 2nd row gives **2 hrs 20 mins.**
and 4th row - 5th row gives **1 hour.** 
So total dependency occurred is **3 Hrs 20 Mins.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Currently, the question is tagged with both.

Comment: Please specify the version of SQL Server you are using, 2008, 2012, ...?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use sql server 2012 or higher, you can use [`lead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) to solve this:

```
;with cte1 as 
(
select  TicketNumber, 
        Action, 
        date,
        lead(date) over(partition by TicketNumber order by date) as nextActionDate
from table1
), cte2 as
(
select TicketNumber, 
       sum(datediff(minute, date, nextActionDate)) as timeOfDependencyOccured
from cte1 
where Action = 'Dependency Occured'
group by TicketNumber
)

select TicketNumber, 
       cast(timeOfDependencyOccured / 60 as varchar(2)) + ':' + 
       cast(timeOfDependencyOccured % 60 as varchar(2))
from cte2
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7b9f/19)

for 2005 / 2008 you will have to use a sub query instead of lead:

```
;with cte1 as 
(
select  TicketNumber, 
        Action, 
        date,
        (select top 1 date 
         from table1 t2
         where t2.date > t1.date
         and t2.TicketNumber = t1.TicketNumber
         order by date
        ) as nextActionDate
from table1 t1
), cte2 as
(
select TicketNumber, 
       sum(datediff(minute, date, nextActionDate)) as timeOfDependencyOccured
from cte1 
where Action = 'Dependency Occured'
group by TicketNumber
)

select TicketNumber, 
       cast(timeOfDependencyOccured / 60 as varchar(2)) + ':' + 
       cast(timeOfDependencyOccured % 60 as varchar(2))
from cte2
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7b9fd/12)

Comment: That's half the problem - the OP wants to sum the durations, something that can't be done with `time` OOTB.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did you see the fiddles? the durations is calculated in the select from the cte and is displayed in the column I've called `timeOfDependencyOccured`. Of course, if it's over 24 hours between records this query will fail, but that's easily fixable by using `datediff` on minutes and formatting the number of minutes on the presentation layer. I've chosen the time since it's the closest thing that sql server have to offer to a timespan (that's what the op needs). I see your point but still stands by my answer.

Comment: I didn't doubt that the query will *run* - you can't SUM time values. The "easily fixable" part has resulted in various SO questions with many different answers. The answers will probably be different for 2012 vs 2008

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see what you mean now. fixed in my edited answer.

Comment: Zohar I gess  
    `where t2.date > t1.date`  
needs to be replaced with  
    `where t2.date > t1.date AND t2.TicketNumber=t1.TicketNumber`   
And why do not use  
    `SELECT TicketNumber, cast(dateadd(minute,timeOfDependencyOccured,0) as time(0)) FROM cte2`
instead of your constuction  
    `select TicketNumber, 
        cast(timeOfDependencyOccured / 60 as varchar(2)) + ':' + 
        cast(timeOfDependencyOccured % 60 as varchar(2))
    from cte2`

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov good catch, thanks! edited my answer. about casting to time, it's limiting the answer to sql server 2008 or higher, and also the maximum sum of time to 24 hours or less.